# Django model property with dictionary data

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I'm trying to access a property/computed field that contains a dictionary within my template I'm not quite sure on how I should be looping over the values, and from a code standpoint is this the correct way to go...  As you can see below, my view creates a filter queryset and my hope is that each row within that queryset will contain the dict from the computed field/property from the model.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  I'm having a hard time determining what would be the correct way to loop over the data in the template itself.  The final product would look something like this...

```
<div id={{provider.id}}>{{provider.name}}</div>
  <div class="dayofweek">Monday</div>
    <div class="timesavailable">
       <ul>
         <li>8:00</li>
         <li>8:30></li>
     </div>
```

Model:

```
from project.lib.file import GetSchedule
class Provider(models.Model):
....
@property
def current_schedule(self):
  sched = GetSchedule(self.id)
  return sched.returnSchedule()
```

Helper Function:

```
class GetSchedule(object):
    schedule = {}
    def __init__(self, provider_id):
        self.provider = provider_id
        try:
            self.schedule = GetSchedule.__buildSchedule(self,self.provider)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            print "Init failed - Cannot find provider in db with id:  %s" % self.provider
            raise ValueError

    def __buildSchedule(self, provider):
        #default values for now - dict will contain data soon
        pid = self.provider
        sched = {'Monday':{'8:00','8:30','10:00'}, 'Tuesday':{'10:00','10:30','11:00'}, 'Wednesday':{'9:30','10:00','10:30'}}
        val = {
            'Schedule' : sched
        }
        return val
    def returnSchedule(self):
        return self.schedule
```

View:

```
prov_list = Provider.objects.filter(docspeciality__name=dft_spec)
context_dict = {
            'DftSpec': dft_spec,
            'DftZip': dft_zip,
            'DftIns': dft_ins,
            'DocList': prov_list}
return render_to_response('search/provider.html', context_dict, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: And what is the exact problem you have at the moment? What do you get when you try this?

Comment: At the moment, I can't seem to get the data out of the Dict in the template.  I am getting an error stating GetSchedule object is not iterable `{% for key, item in provider.current_schedule %}
                    {{ key }}
                    {% for inneritem in item.current_schedule %}
                        {{ inneritem }}
                        {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}`

Comment: Never mind - the template is displaying now.  I had to change the dict inside of a dict to a list inside of a dict...